# Joining on multiple possible tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, polymorphic-associations

Consider the following schema on this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ca36/5). As you can see it follows the supertable schema for modeling a polymorphic association. Take in mind that foo, bar, and baz tables are very different each other on the real implementation.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to retrieve all the activities for a given owner with its corresponding target, my first idea was to use multiple LEFT OUTER JOINS:

```
SELECT *
FROM activities
LEFT OUTER JOIN foo ON activities.target_id = foo.activitable_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON activities.target_id = bar.activitable_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN baz ON activities.target_id = baz.activitable_id
WHERE activities.owner_id = 1
```

This query *is fine* considering I'm only joining 3 tables with one row on each table, but when the schema grows up to 8 joins with 10k rows on each table there's a huge performance impact.

So my question is, there's any way to achieve what I want with a faster query?

Comment: add indexes on the foreign keys

Comment: Are you sure your query is fine? I think it multiplies foo/bar/baz records. You could use union, I think.

Comment: Selecting just the fields you need instead of selecting * is always faster because there is less data to transfer.

Comment: @Arvo it works fine for me. The only issue is that it returns duplicated fields, but its easy to workaround using coalesce() to return just the not-null results. Not sure if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't need to be a huge performance impact.  You have defined your data structure with only one index per table, the one on the primary key.  That means that the joins are less efficient than they could be.

Also, given your structure, I don't think you want duplicate `activitable_id`s in any of the tables.  So, each table should be defined something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id serial primary key,
  name varchar(20),
  activitable_id int UNIQUE,
  FOREIGN KEY (activitable_id) REFERENCES activitables(id)
);
```

Declaring the `activitable_id` to be unique addresses both these problems, because it creates a unique index on the column that both enforces uniqueness and should improve performance.

Comment: You're absolutely right, although @Donal noted that on a comment before, you're answer is the most complete. I still don't know how I missed to add the indexes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could add indexes on the columns that are used in the query:

```
activities.target_id
foo.activitable_id
bar.activitable_id    
baz.activitable_id
```

If there is any filter condition that you can apply on any of the tables, then the performance would be better also, because you would be operating on a smaller subset of data. For example,

```
SELECT *
FROM activities
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name like 'A%') foo ON activities.target_id = foo.activitable_id --Filter applied to limit rows using the name
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM bar WHERE id < 10) bar ON activities.target_id = bar.activitable_id --Filter applied to limit rows using id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM baz WHERE activitable_id = 1) baz ON activities.target_id = baz.activitable_id --Filter applied to limit rows using activitable_id
WHERE activities.owner_id = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I don't know if it is my browser, but there seems to be something going on with the formatting.

Comment: The formatting is fine! Your tip helps improving the performance as well, thank you!